# Combinar filas en flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Buen día, estoy intentando hacer esta imagen de Piet Mondrian usando HTML y CSS para practicar lo que aprendí de Flexbox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo una buena parte del problema resuelto, pero lo que me está presentando dificultades es como combinar las filas. Por ejemplo, en la izquierda donde hay un cuadrado rojo, necesito combinar las cuatro filas para hacer el cuadrado rojo. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 16px solid #292827;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sub-container1 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border-right: 8px solid #292827;
}

.sub-container2 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.sub-container1 > div {
  height: 10%;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #292827;
}

.sub-container1 div:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-container2 > div {
  height: 10%;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #292827; 
}

.sub-container2 div:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.flex-item1,
.flex-item2,
.flex-item3,
.flex-item4,
.flex-item5,
.flex-item6,
.flex-item7,
.flex-item8,
.flex-item9,
.flex-item10 {
  display: flex;
}

.a1 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border-right: 8px solid #292827;
}

.a2 {
  flex: 3 0 auto;
  border-right: 8px solid #292827;
}

.a3 {
  flex: 2 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b1 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border-right: 8px solid #292827;
}

.b2 {
  flex: 4 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-right: 8px solid #292827;
}

.b3 {
  flex: 2.5 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c1 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border-right: 8px solid #292827;
}

.c2 {
  flex: 4 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-right: 8px solid #292827;
}

.c3 {
  flex: 1.25 0 auto;
  border-right: 8px solid #292827; 
}

.c4 {
  flex: 1.25 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container1">
    <div class="flex-item1">
      <div class="a1"></div>
      <div class="a2"></div>
      <div class="a3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item2">
      <div class="b1"></div>
      <div class="b2"></div>
      <div class="b3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item3">
      <div class="b1"></div>
      <div class="b2"></div>
      <div class="b3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item4">
      <div class="c1"></div>
      <div class="c2"></div>
      <div class="c3"></div>
      <div class="c4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item5">
      <div class="c1"></div>
      <div class="c2"></div>
      <div class="c3"></div>
      <div class="c4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item6"></div>
    <div class="flex-item7"></div>
    <div class="flex-item8"></div>
    <div class="flex-item9"></div>
    <div class="flex-item10"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container2">
    <div class="flex-item1"></div>
    <div class="flex-item2"></div>
    <div class="flex-item3"></div>
    <div class="flex-item4"></div>
    <div class="flex-item5"></div>
    <div class="flex-item6"></div>
    <div class="flex-item7"></div>
    <div class="flex-item8"></div>
    <div class="flex-item9"></div>
    <div class="flex-item10"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Es mas complicado usar flex. Deberias usar tablas con las propiedades colspan y rowspan. Usando `display: flex` se te va a dificultar mucho

Comment: Diría que es una una mala práctica utilizar flexbox para ejercicios como éstos, mejor te vendría trabajar con tablas y usar colspan o rowspan, te ahorras más trabajo.

Comment: :( Ya se que sería más fácil hacerlo con tablas o usando GRID, pero quiero hacerlo con flexbox. El ejercicio lo saqué de acá: https://github.com/oakmac/flexbox-layout-exercises

Comment: Es probable que se pueda hacer con flexbox creando un contenedor principal con varios contenedores secundarios donde, en cada uno de ellos, se incluyesen bloques de color que entre sí formen un rectángulo o un cuadrado perfecto. Dicho esto, no me parece el mejor ejercicio: se trata de aprender flexbox y claramente no es la mejor solución para resolver el problema.

Comment: Ya pude resolverlo, quité los bordes internos y se los puse a cada div que lo necesitaba para hacer la imagen.